# Separar en horas min y segundos los string de un fichero

Tags: python

Tengo una lista en la que he guardado las lineas de un fichero en el que hay unas horas guardadas en el formato Hora:Min:Seg. El resultado es una lista del tipo
['04:03:22', '15:57:55'] alguien me podria explicar como puedo quitar ese : para poder separar facilmente las horas... Les adjunto hasta donde he llegado

```
lista=[]
linean=""
horas=
min=
seg=
tiempot=""
#Almacenar en la lista todas las lineas del fichero
f=open("ficheroenero.txt")
for lineas in f:
   linean=lineas.rstrip("\n")
   lista.append(linean)
#Almacenar los datos en las variable horas,min,seg

#Convertir la lista en el formato de horas adecuado
def convertir(horas,min,seg):
  while(seg>60 and min>60):
      if(seg>=60): 
          seg-=60
          min+=1 
      if(min>=60): 
          min-=60 
          horas+=1
  tiempot=horas+":"+min+":"+seg
  return tiempot
print(lista)
print(convertir(horas,min,seg))
```

Comment: Tu mejor opción es parsear la hora usando [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Eso te devolverá un objeto [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), del cual podrás obtener la hora.

Comment: ¿Por qué se necesita validar si los segundos o minutos son superiores a 59? ¿Cuál (o cómo) es la salida deseada? Puedes editar la pregunta y colocar una muestra del txt con los datos.

Comment: @aeportugal he hecho una correcion en el while, no me habia fijado que habia puesto un < en vez de >, se necesita validar esto en la funcion convertir porque las variables min, seg tendran almacendados valores superiores a 59 y el resultado final trata de expresar todo esto en el formato hora:min:seg y para esto no puedo tener 80 minutos por ejemplo, lo correcto deberia ser 1 hora y 20 minutos (0:80:0-----1:20:0)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No se de Python pero quizás esto te pueda ayudar. Yo en java uso un método llamado split que lo que hace es que separa una cadena por el caracter que nosotros le introduzcamos y nos guarda esos trozos de cadena en un array de string. Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
String hora = "13:00:23"
String [] horas = hora.split(":")
```

El resultado sería el siguiente

```
String[0] = 13
String[1] = 00
String[2] = 23
```

Espero que te sirva de algo

Comment: muchas gracias por el comentario justo acabo de conseguir hacerlo yo tambien pero se agradece el interes

Comment: De nada‍

Comment: Java y python son totalmente distintos, en este caso tienes suerte que también exista el método `split` pero no siempre será así, incluso podría haber una opción más pythonica por la que optar. Si no tienes mucho conocimiento del lenguaje puedes buscar y si no puedes dejar un comentario tratando de guiar al usuario, pero no una respuesta que está en un lenguaje distinto y que posiblemente no solucione el problema

Comment: El split de java no hace lo mismo que el de Python. La cadena que acepta el split de java es un regex.

Comment: Vale lo tendre en cuenta para las siguientes, pensaba q si le decia la solucion en otro lenguaje alomejor le aclaraba algo y podia haber la posibilidad de "traducir" de un lenguaje a otro. La prox no pondrr nada

Comment: Ademas de lo dicho anteriormente, no todos tienen conocimiento suficiente de java como para hacer la "traducción". Por ejemplo, no todos saben que significa "String[]". Y otra cosa, este sitio no está pensado para guiar usuarios, si no para dar respuestas que resuelvan dudas. Y una tercera cosa, como dije en mi comentario anterior, el split de java acepta un regex, es una coincidencia que separar una cadena usando el regex ":" haga lo mismo que separar usando la cadena ":". Aun así, gracias por tu intento de aportar y ayudar y espero hayas aprendido algo nuevo c:

Answer (score 1):

Cómo ya te han dicho en los comentarios puedes usar el módulo `datetime` el cual te ayuda al manejo de fechas incluida las horas.

```py
from datetime import datetime

horas = ['04:03:22', '15:57:55']

horas = [datetime.strptime(hora, '%H:%M:%S') for hora in horas]
print(horas)
```

Esto convertirá el string a un objeto `datetime` del cual ya puedes acceder a atributos como `hour` para acceder a la hora, `minute` para los minutos y `second` para los segundos.

Al tener las horas en un objeto `datetime` te permite hacer operaciones con ellas, por ejemplo sumar o restar ya sea horas, minutos o segundo, esto con ayuda de otra clase llamada `timedelta`

Por ejemplo si quiere sumar 1 hora a la primera hora puedes hacer esto:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

horas = ['04:03:22', '15:57:55']

horas = [datetime.strptime(hora, '%H:%M:%S') for hora in horas]

hora_mas_1 = horas[0] + timedelta(hours=1)

print(hora_mas_1)
```

Con esto obtendrás este resultado:

```
1900-01-01 05:03:22
```

El resultado incluye el año, mes y día, pero como no se han especificado se colocan unos por defecto. Si quieres que al momento de imprimir o mostrar las horas no aparezca la fecha, entonces usa el método `strftime` indicando el formato a convertir la hora.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

horas = ['04:03:22', '15:57:55']

horas = [datetime.strptime(hora, '%H:%M:%S') for hora in horas]

hora_mas_1 = horas[0] + timedelta(hours=1)

print(hora_mas_1)

hora_str = hora_mas_1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(hora_str)
```